# Error while Recording Audio on watch-os-3

Tags: avfoundation, swift3, xcode8, watchconnectivity, watchos-3

I wanted to record my Audio on Applewatch and send to my iPhone.
I created a URL to store the file and everytime I try this on my simulator it is working fine but on real device nothing happes with this error

> Error: Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=3 “(null)”

**URL:**

```
var dir = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.companyname.projektname")
```

**RECORD:**

```
presentAudioRecorderController(withOutputURL: dir,preset:.narrowBandSpeech,
                                                            options: nil,
                                                            completion:.........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On WatchOS 3 you also need to add a "Privacy - Microphone Usage Description" entry in the info.plist file of your iOS app (not the WatchKit app). Then on the iPhone you must agree with using the microphone.

I found this here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62612

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

**Define URL :**

```
var saveUrl: NSURL?

let container = 
    fileManager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier(
        "group.com.companyname.projektname")

let fileName = "audioFile.wav"

saveUrl = container?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
```

**Recording Code :**

```
let duration = NSTimeInterval(10)

let recordOptions = 
         [WKAudioRecorderControllerOptionsMaximumDurationKey : duration]

presentAudioRecorderControllerWithOutputURL(saveUrl!, 
         preset: .NarrowBandSpeech,
         options: recordOptions, 
         completion: { saved, error in

            if let err = error {
                print(err.description)
            }

            if saved {
                self.playButton.setEnabled(true)
            }
      })
```

Hope this will help you...